# JSON deserialization to object fails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

```
return jsSerializer.Deserialize<MamDataResponseHolder>(stringJson);
```

throws an exception:

> *Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.*

But I don't see the problem.

```
 public class MamDataResponseHolder
    {
        public MamDataResponsePair[] configuration { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

  public class MamDataResponsePair
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public MamDataResponsecriteria[] criterias { get; set; }
    }

 public class MamDataResponsecriteria
    {
        public Guid criteriaId { get; set; }
        public string[] domains { get; set; }
        public string domainsException { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the json:

```
    {
        "configuration": [{
            "id": "Coupon Body",
            "criterias": [{
                "criteriaId": "c7150fc2-72b9-4628-a199-dd5c0bdeef1b",
                "domains": [""],
                "domainsException": [""]
            }]
        }],
        "Status": "succeeded"
    }
```

Comment: `"domainsException": [""]` - this is serialized as an array, but in the model it is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model and your Json do not match. Take a look at `domainsException`. In your Json it's clearly a string-array, but in your model it's just a string.

Besides that: Are you sure you want `[""]` in your Json? That way you get an array with an empty string instead of an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Your Classes should be like below:

```
public class Criteria
{
    public string criteriaId { get; set; }
    public List<string> domains { get; set; }
    public List<string> domainsException { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Criteria> criterias { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Configuration> configuration { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why? There's absolutely no need to rename the classes and use List instead of arrays. Besides that you did not even mention the exact problem.

Comment: Yes no need to rename the classes but it is good practice to keep name same as you getting response because if you again serialize it later you can get same as input string.

Comment: Then you really should mention your intend in your answer.